# aptitude wants to install old kernels I just purged

Tags: aptitude

My (14.04) boot partition was filling up, so I researched how to purge old kernels and found lots of help. I kept the current (determined using uname -a) and the prior kernel and purged several older than that using apt-get purge. Now apititude wants to reinstall the ones I just purged. I get green "pi" install prompts for each.

Is this expected behavior? Am I going to have to check my current version and tell aptitude to skip older ones every time I use aptitude? Is there a step I missed?

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get autoremove` for that. It safely and correctly removes  all but the current one and the previous as backup. Do not manually remove kernels unless you have to due to something unwise you might have done. Also Aptitude isn't required.

Comment: According to the autoremove dry-run, the only thing it wants to remove is the one old version that I'm keeping as a backup. It does not say anything about ones older than that that I've already purged.

Comment: If you run it then it should try to reinstall them unless, of course, something unwise has been done already. In that case: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: Are you suggesting I let aptitude reinstall all the old kernels I just purged?

Comment: FWIW dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' gives me a list of kernels older than the ones I purged, marked 'rc', and newer than the ones I purged, marked 'ii'. The ones I purged are not shown at all.

Comment: Exactly what method did you use to purge the older kernels and remove all record of their package from the dpkg database? That seems bad.

Comment: Does `aptitude why linux-image-X.X.X-XX-generic` (for any/all of the kernel packages it wants to re-install) shed any light?

Comment: I used apt-get purge. `Aptitude why` shows the same dependency chain for all kernel versions, past and present, the last entry `linux-image` fulfilled by a version that is currently installed and current.

Comment: This happens to me as well. I just hit - on the green prompts.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` so we can see the state of your kernel packages.